# How to see .mmdb file content?

Tags: database, viewer, maxmind, geolite2

I have a file `GeoLite2-City.mmdb` which is MaxMind DB File.

I want to see its content.

What is a way to see the content of this `.mmdb` file? Does MaxMind offer a tool or a library to be able to read such files?

Comment: Why don't you just download the CSV file?

Answer (score 17):

See Maxmind's [mmdb file specification](https://maxmind.github.io/MaxMind-DB/).

mmdb databases are self contained "search tree indexed files" so you cannot just sequentially read and display the file record by record (even its "data records" include pointers to other "cache" data records that contain the actual human readable strings such as country name). So the sort of view provided by text editors is no use - you need an equivalent of the "table" row viewer for MySQL in phpMyAdmin allowing both "sequential" display or look-up by IP.

As far as I am aware no such viewer is available. They are huge files and if you just wish to view out of interest then its not worth the effort.

A capable programmer *could* write their own viewer, but I would describe the task as *challenging* (and I started programming creating and navigating suites of indexed sequential files on a pre-DBMS IBM mainframe). Maxmind's post on [building (and reading) your own MMDB](https://blog.maxmind.com/2015/09/29/building-your-own-mmdb-database-for-fun-and-profit/)  will provide useful pointers.

**The above specification contains links to Reader Libraries/Packages** in various languages and you could use or add to these existing Reader functions (e.g. for PHP Reader see [Reader.php](https://github.com/maxmind/MaxMind-DB-Reader-php/blob/master/src/MaxMind/Db/Reader.php) and [Decoder.php](https://github.com/maxmind/MaxMind-DB-Reader-php/blob/master/src/MaxMind/Db/Reader/Decoder.php))

For "sequential" display you will need to iterate through the file (e.g. [Perl:  iterate_search_tree](https://metacpan.org/pod/MaxMind::DB::Reader#$reader-%3Eiterate_search_tree(-$data_callback,-$node_callback-)) ). I'm not sure if an equivalent function is directly built in to all of Maxminds Readers or whether you will  have to extend.

Comment: If it's a search tree shouldn't a simple dfs search return a sequential result?!